# How to compare two data types in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class `Vehicule` and 3 subclasses `Voiture`, `Camion` and `Moto`.
I also have a method `getVehicules` for the all vehicules  (i.e. camion, voiture, moto) but I want to print
a specific type like Voiture.

I don't know how to solve  it .

```
 List<Vehicule> vehicules = new ArrayList<>();

    public void getVehicules() {
            vehicules.forEach(vehicule->{
                System.out.println(vehicule);
            });     

     }
    
    public void getVoitures() {
        Iterator iterator = vehicules.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {

      //I want to do a condtion if vehicule is voiture it will disaplay

            if(vehicules.equals(voiture)) {
                System.out.println(iterator);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use `instanceof`.

Comment: Note: `System.out.println(iterator);` will print the iterator object!

Answer (score 1):

## Pattern matching with `switch`

A new feature being previewed in [Java 20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_20) enables using a `switch` statement to test for subclasses. See: [*JEP 433: Pattern Matching for switch (Fourth Preview)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/433).

```java
switch ( véhicule )
{
    case Voiture v -> System.out.println( "Voici une voiture." );
    case Camion c -> System.out.println( "Voici un camion." );
    case Moto m -> System.out.println( "Voici une moto." );
    default -> System.out.println( "Ooops! Il n'y a pas de véhicule." );
}
```

Wrap that in a for-each loop. Here is a complete example `.java` file.

```java
package work.basil.example.subs;

import java.util.List;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        List < Véhicule > véhicules = List.of( new Voiture() , new Camion() , new Moto() );

        for ( Véhicule véhicule : véhicules )
        {
            switch ( véhicule )
            {
                case Voiture v -> System.out.println( "Voici une voiture." );
                case Camion c -> System.out.println( "Voici un camion." );
                case Moto m -> System.out.println( "Voici une moto." );
                default -> System.out.println( "Ooops! Il n'y a pas de véhicule." );
            }
        }
    }
}

class Véhicule { }

class Voiture extends Véhicule { }

class Camion extends Véhicule { }

class Moto extends Véhicule { }
```

When run:

```
Voici une voiture.
Voici un camion.
Voici une moto.
```

### `default` case

Notice the `default` at the bottom of the `switch` to catch any other subclasses that may defined at the end.

Another new feature delivered in Java 17 can eliminate the need for that `default`, if we choose to disallow further direct subclasses. The new feature is *sealed classes*. See [*JEP 409: Sealed Classes*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/409). This feature defines a way to declare a list of known subclasses, and to declare that no more will be allowed. Therefore the compiler knows at compile-time all possible subclasses. The compiler can then check that your `switch` statement has covered all the possibilities.

```java
sealed class Véhicule permits Voiture, Camion, Moto { }

final class Voiture extends Véhicule { }

final class Camion extends Véhicule { }

final class Moto extends Véhicule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to compare two data type in Java
> You can get the type (a `java.lang.Class`) of an object using `object.getClass()`.

You can compare two classes using `equals(...)`; e.g.

```
if (obj1.getClass().equals(obj2.getClass())
```

You can test if an object has a specific class in a couple of ways

```
if (obj.getClass().equals(Car.class))
```

or

```
if (obj instanceof Car)
```

(They do slightly different things.  The latter tests if `obj` is a `Car` or a subclass of `Car` and will return `false` if `obj` is `null`.)

There are methods on the `Class` class that will give the classes simple name or its full name ... or you can just use the `Class.toString()` method.

---

Just for the record, another way to solve the problem that doesn't involve using the class names would be to define a second (abstract) method in the superclass that returns a String that denotes the kind of the vehicle; e.g.

```
   public abstract class Vehicle {
      ...
      public abstract String getType();
   }

   public class Car extends Vehicle {
      
      @Override
      public String getType() {
          return "Car";
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, instanceof would help here :-

```
class Vehicule {

}

class Voiture extends Vehicule {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Voiture";
    }
}

class Camion extends Vehicule {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Camion";
    }
}

class Moto extends Vehicule {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Moto";
    }
}

public class Operation {
    
    static List<Vehicule> vehicules = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        vehicules.add(new Camion());
        vehicules.add(new Moto());
        vehicules.add(new Voiture());
        //Prints all objects
        getVehicules();
        //Prints only voiture
        getVoitures();

    }

    public static void getVehicules() {
        vehicules.forEach(vehicule -> {
            System.out.println(vehicule);
        });

    }

    public static void getVoitures() {
        Iterator iterator = vehicules.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Object vehicule = iterator.next();
            if (vehicule instanceof Voiture) {
                System.out.println(vehicule);
            }
        }
    }


}
```